# Regex in Spark NLP Normalizer is not working correctly

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I'm using the Spark NLP pipeline to preprocess my data. Instead of only removing punctuation, the normalizer also removes umlauts.

My code:

```
documentAssembler = DocumentAssembler() \
    .setInputCol("column") \
    .setOutputCol("column_document")\
    .setCleanupMode('shrink_full')

tokenizer = Tokenizer() \
  .setInputCols(["column_document"]) \
  .setOutputCol("column_token") \
  .setMinLength(2)\
  .setMaxLength(30)
  
normalizer = Normalizer() \
    .setInputCols(["column_token"]) \
    .setOutputCol("column_normalized")\
    .setCleanupPatterns(["[^\w -]|_|-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-"])\
    .setLowercase(True)\
```

Example:

```
Ich esse gerne Äpfel vom Biobauernhof Reutter-Müller, die schmecken besonders gut!
```

Output:

```
Ich esse gerne pfel vom Biobauernhof Reutter Mller die schmecken besonders gut
```

Expected Output:

```
Ich esse gerne Äpfel vom Biobauernhof Reutter-Müller die schmecken besonders gut
```

Comment: Try `"(?U)[^\w -]|_|-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-"`

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot! Could you give me a small explanation why it's working with "(?U)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\w` pattern is not Unicode-aware by default, you need to make it Unicode-aware with a regex option. In this case, it is easier to do it with an [embedded flag option `(?U)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS):

```java
"(?U)[^\w -]|_|-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-"
```

More details from the documentation:

> When this flag is specified then the (US-ASCII only) *Predefined character classes* and *POSIX character classes* are in conformance with [*Unicode Technical Standard #18: Unicode Regular Expression*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/) *Annex C: Compatibility Properties*.
>
> The UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression `(?U)`.
>
> The flag implies UNICODE_CASE, that is, it enables Unicode-aware case folding.